# Помогите доделать команду warn в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, discord.py

Есть код:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = 'Не указана'):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(f"./DataBase/Servers/{member.guild.name}/Players/{member.name}{member.discriminator}.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO '{member.name}'
            VALUES ('{reason}')"""
            )
    conn.commit()
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT warns FROM '{member.name}'""")
    warn = discord.Embed(description=f'**{member.mention} Было выдано предупреждение\nПричина: {reason}\nКем: {ctx.author.mention}**', color=0x940006)
    await ctx.send(embed=warn)
    
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def warns(self, ctx, member: discord.Member): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect(f"./DataBase/Servers/{member.guild.name}/Players/{member.name}{member.discriminator}.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT warns FROM '{member.name}'""")
    warn1 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if warn1 is not None:
        warn = discord.Embed(description=f'**Предупреждения {member.mention}:\n1. {warn1}**', color=0x940006)
        await ctx.send(embed=warn)
    else:
        nwarn = discord.Embed(description=f'У {member.mention} Нет предупреждений')
        await ctx.send(embed=nwarn)
```

warn выдаёт предупреждение участнику и сохраняет в локальной бд

warns показывает все предупреждения игрока

Как сделать так чтобы выводилось не только 1 предупреждение, но и остальные например 3? (по записям) т.е каждое новое добавляется ввиде новой записи

Answer (score 0):

Вот, пожалуйста:

```
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT warns FROM '{member.name}'""")
warn1 = cursor.fetchall()

m = []

for w in range(len(warn1)):
    m.append(m)

print('\n'.join(m))
```